# Simplifying summation expression involving sample mean

Tags: statistics, summation

I have the following expression

$$T \sum_{t} x_{t}^{2}-\left(\sum_{t} x_{t}\right)^{2}$$ (where $T>0$, and the $x_{t} s$ are being summed over $T$ periods) which I am trying to simplify to $$T \sum_{t}\left(x_{t}-\bar{x}\right)^{2}$$

So far I have that $$T \sum_{t} x_{t}^{2}-\left(\sum_{t} x_{t}\right)^{2} =T \sum_{t} x_{t}^{2} -\left( T\bar{x}\right)^{2}$$

However, beyond this, I am stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: I would probably start from the second expression and work backwards to the first by expanding the binomial into three terms.  Then you can work it forwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial expression can be rewritten as follows

$$T^2\left[\frac{1}{T}\Sigma_iX_i^2\right]-T^2\left(\overline{X}_T  \right)^2=T^2S_X^2$$

where $S_X^2$ is the sample variance (biased estimator of $\sigma^2$))

thus you have

$$T^2\left[\frac{1}{T}\Sigma_i(X_i-\overline{X}_T)^2  \right]$$

which is exactly what  you are looking for